# XmlNode.RemoveChild() method does not work as expected

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to remove specific node from xml document by looping through it. Here is what I have tried:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes) {
    if (node.Name == "EmbeddedResource" && node.Attributes["Include"].Value.Contains(".resx")) {
           node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
     }
}
```

Nothing happens when this code is executed. No exception is thrown also. I have googled a little and found some solution with `SelectSingleNode` method but it requires XPath as input parameter and it is too complicated in my opinion, because I already have the node that I want. This is how it looks like (by the way, I couldn't make it work because there is something wrong with my XPath):

```
parentNode.RemoveChild(parentNode.SelectSingleNode("//" + parentNode.Name + "/" + node.Name + "[@Include='" + node.Attributes["Include"].Value + "']"));
```

Why is this method behaving like this?
Is there a way to do this differently?

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're iterating through doc.ChildNodes, why don't you use doc.RemoveChild(node)?

Also there may be a problem in that you're iterating through a list whilst removing items from that list - I don't know how C# would handle that. You could, for example, store a temporary list of nodes to delete in your original foreach and then iterate through the temporary list to delete the items from the doc.

Comment: Temporary list worked. I suppose the problem was, as you said, iterating through a list and trying to remove item from it. Thanks.

Comment: Odd that no exception was thrown though!